# I have a DLL program and am trying to update it with Descriptions but can't get them to work

Tags: vb.net, dll, properties, browsable, field-description

I have a DLL program that I wrote a few years back and am trying to update it with `Description`s but can't get them to work.

Here is my code:

```vbnet
<Browsable(True)>
<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)>
<Description("Get email Information")>
<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)>
Public Function getemail(ByVal source As String) As String()
```

and this is what I am trying to do - the part in the circle:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting this before

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get email Information
    /// </summary>
```